# How to give dynamic value for NEXT_N_MONTHS in apex query

Tags: apex, soql

I have a requirement where I have to query data of next 'n' months, so I am not able to give this in apex query, its taking only integer not an integer variable.

Code Snippet is given below.

```
Integer dynamicDate = Integer.valueOf(date.today().addMonths(3).month());
            jpActivityRecordsLIST = [SELECT ID,
                                     FROM JourneyPlanActivity__c 
                                     WHERE (date__c = LAST_MONTH OR date__c = THIS_MONTH OR  date__c = NEXT_N_MONTHS:dynamicDate )
                                     AND CreatedById =: userRecord.Id];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but you could calculate those yourself:

```
Integer dynamicDate = Integer.valueOf(date.today().addMonths(3).month());
Date startDate = Date.today().toStartOfMonth().addMonths(-1),
     endDate = Date.today().addMonths(dynamicDate).toStartOfMonth().addDays(-1);
            jpActivityRecordsLIST = [SELECT ID,
                                     FROM JourneyPlanActivity__c 
                                     WHERE (date__c >= :startDate AND Date__c <= :endDate)
                                     AND CreatedById =: userRecord.Id];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative it to turn this into a dynamic query:

```
Integer dynamicDate = Integer.valueOf(date.today().addMonths(3).month());
Id userRecordId = userRecord.Id;
jpActivityRecordsLIST = Database.query(
    'SELECT ID ' +
        'FROM JourneyPlanActivity__c ' +
        'WHERE (date__c = LAST_MONTH ' +
            'OR date__c = THIS_MONTH ' +
            'OR date__c = NEXT_N_MONTHS:' + dynamicDate + ') ' +
        'AND CreatedById = :userRecordId');
```

Points to note:

- Direct inclusion of the dynamicDate value into the query string by concatenation
- Changing the userRecord.Id into a simple value binding, without dot notation, as is required by dynamic SOQL

PS: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do here by using a year month number as your NEXT_N_MONTHS figure. Why do you want to check the date in this way? It seems a bit strange.